# Amcharts remove clip-path for <g>

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I have an amchart with icons LineSeries() and I set them to be a little off the chart, so they are cut off. I tried to use `chart.maskBullets = false` - did not work. Now I see there is a `clip-path="url("#id-2579")"` for the group `<g>` of these icons. If I remove it with the chrome console - everything looks fine. Is it possible to remove this prop with the amchart API (or how to set an id for this group)? Thanks

`<g class="amcharts-Sprite-group amcharts-Container-group amcharts-Series-bullets-group amcharts-XYSeries-bullets-group amcharts-LineSeries-bullets-group" fill="#6771dc" stroke="#6771dc" clip-path="url('#id-2579')">`
[image]
example https://codepen.io/benderlidze/pen/OJwdoYe?editors=0010

Comment: Could you please share your code? It is difficult to help you if we cannot reproduce the problem...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in this line

```
//chart.leftAxesContainer.layout = 'vertical'
```

When I commented it out, it worked.